SMTP Port 25 Issue on Nginx Mail Proxy
I set up an Nginx mail proxy server and configured it to distribute to several mail servers as a front-end server. However, I need to open port 25 in the configuration; otherwise, I cannot receive mail. When I open port 25, I have to enable the smtp_auth plain login feature; otherwise, if someone knows my email address, they can send mail without a password.
When I enable the smtp_auth feature, I can't receive emails when someone sends an email to my address from outside.
For example, when I try to send an email from Gmail to my server, the message returned by Gmail mail delivery is as follows:
The remote server's response was:
530 5.7.1 Authentication required
How can I resolve this issue?
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (mail {} partition)
mail {

   server_name mail.proxyserver.com;
   auth_http localhost/auth/auth.php;
   pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER" "UIDL" "PIPELINING" "SASL";
   imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS" "IDLE" "LITERAL+" "QUOTA";
   smtp_capabilities "SIZE 53477376" "8BITMIME" "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES" "PIPELINING" "DSN";

   proxy on;
   proxy_pass_error_message on;
   proxy_timeout 300s;

    starttls                   on;
    ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers                HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_session_cache          shared:TLSSL:16m;
    ssl_session_timeout        10m;
    ssl_certificate            /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.proxyserver.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key        /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.proxyserver.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam        /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    server {
            listen     25;
            listen     [::]:25;
            protocol   smtp;
            starttls   only;
            smtp_auth  none; # my problem :(
            xclient    off;
    }

    server {
            listen     465 ssl;
            listen     [::]:465 ssl;
            protocol   smtp;
    }

    server {
            listen     587;
            listen     [::]:587;
            protocol   smtp;
            starttls   only;
    }

    server {
            listen     110;
            listen     [::]:110;
            protocol   pop3;
            starttls   only;
    }

    server {
            listen     995 ssl;
            listen     [::]:995 ssl;
            protocol   pop3;
    }

    server {
            listen     143;
            listen     [::]:143;
            protocol   imap;
            starttls   only;
    }

    server {
            listen     993 ssl;
            listen     [::]:993 ssl;
            protocol   imap;
    }
}


I had the exact same problem, but I also found a solution: For port 25 there must be no authentication (smtp_auth none;). You then get the request passed to your auth script. In your script you have to check, that the RCPT TO contains the domain you are handling with your mailserver. If so you can let the mail pass, otherwise you have to cancel the authentication request by sending the appropriate headers and thus reject the incoming mail.
ATTENTION: if you do not do reject other maildomains you have an open relay!
if (!preg_match('/^RCPT TO:\s*<[^@]+@example\.com>/i', $headers['auth-smtp-to'])){
    header('Auth-Status: Authentication required');
    header('Auth-Error-Code: 530 5.7.1');
    exit(0);
}

Please be aware, that I also converted all headers to lowercase letters before accessing them.
Also I would recommend using the xclient. If you are using postfix you can ensure that only the nginx proxy can access the xclient settings by using:
smtpd_authorized_xclient_hosts = IP_OF_YOUR_NGINX_HOST

You then have the correct IP of the connecting client in your mail headers which your spam filter can pick up and thus handle better.
